# How do I select values from a list based on character length?

Tags: r, csv

I am working on a program that follows this basic logic:

1. Read 3 CSV files, the first two of which contain keywords and the last one of which contains exclusion words.
2. Combine the two keyword lists into one thing, capitalizing all keywords and **removing any keywords that are less than 3 characters**.
3. Sort and remove duplicate keywords from the keyword list.
4. Capitalize all of the words in the exclusion list.
5. Remove keywords that have a match in the exclusion list.

It is step 2 that I am having trouble with. I've tried quite a few solutions but nothing is working. Here is my code:

```
# Read in individual data sets

set1=read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
set2=read.csv("set2.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
exclude_list=read.csv("exclude.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")

# Create a new set with the aggregate of all keyword sets,
# capitalizing all keywords and excluding keywords that are 
# less than 2 characters in length

set_agg=rbind(set1,set2)
keywords=set_agg[c("V1")]
keywords = as.data.frame(sapply(keywords, toupper))

??? WHAT GOES HERE ???

# Sort and remove duplicate keywords from the keyword list
as.data.frame(keywords[order(keywords$V1),])
keywords=unique(keywords)

# Modify and capitalize the exclusion list

exclude_list=as.data.frame(exclude_list[c("V1")])
exclude_list=as.data.frame(sapply(exclude_list, toupper))   

# Remove keywords matching the exclude list

`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)

keywords=subset(keywords, V1 %ni% exclude_list$V1)

return(keywords)
```

For reference, the CSV files are formatted like this:

```
word1,
word2,
word3,
etc...
```

Comment: See the `toupper` and `nchar` functions. Also: `c(1,2,3)[ ! c(1,2,3) %in% c(1,2) ]` is a way to say : give me the elements from {1,2,3} that are not in { 1,2 }

Comment: @arvi1000 Or `setdiff(c(1,2,3),c(1,2))`

Comment: Right, or that! Showed the above since OP was already using `%in%`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by indexing with an sapply on the length of the keywords:

```
keywords[sapply(keywords[,1], nchar) > 2,]
```

**UPDATE** Here is a full version that is a little simpler using vectors:

```
## Assuming you have keywords and exclude_list originally stored as vectors
keywords <- sapply(unique(sort(c(set1, set2))), toupper)
keywords <- keywords[nchar(keywords) > 2]
keywords <- setdiff(keywords, sapply(exclude_list, toupper))
```

Comment: No, you want nchar, not length! `length('hi')` is 1. `nchar('hi')` is 2

Comment: thanks @Frank and arvi1000. Also is there a reason for using data.frames here? Seems like vectors would be a bit easier.

Comment: Nice edit. No need to highlight with "Update" etc. The edit history is visible for those interested, and it's best to just have the answer in it's best possible state. The last operation might be less costly if unique is also applied to the exclude list; and `setdiff(x,y)` is an alternative to `x[ ! x %in% y ]`

Comment: I'm just really new to the language and couldn't get anything to work without everything being data frames.  Also when I run your code (the original, not the UPDATE version), I get an error that says "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector".  Thoughts?

Comment: Also when I tried your UPDATE code, I get the error "Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic "

Comment: I just got it to work using this actually: agg=function()
{
 # Read in individual data sets
 
 set1=as.character(read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")$V1)
 set2=as.character(read.csv("set2.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")$V1)
 exclude_list=read.csv("exclude.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
 
 keywords <- sapply(unique(sort(c(set1, set2))), toupper)
 keywords <- keywords[nchar(keywords) > 2]
 keywords <- setdiff(keywords, sapply(exclude_list, toupper))
 
 return(keywords)
}

Comment: Indeed. The default for reading in files is to read characters as factors. IMHO, this is one of the worst defaults ever. Your fix of explicitly converting to characters is the correct solution. Alternatively you can add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your `read.csv` call to change this default behavior.